# how to count item from item name in excel worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

example how to count item from item name in excel worksheet

product name

1.micromaax mobil
2.nokia mobile
3.micromaax mobil
4.nokia mobile
5.micromaax mobil
6.nokia mobile           How i count it in excel how much sold

Answer (score 0):

You can use `countif` function for that.

See the image below for formula and usage

[image]

Reference : https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function